# How to map a port range from host to docker?

Tags: docker

It is OK to map several ports via the command:

docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 8000:8000 container_name

However, if I want to map the wide range 5000-5100, I have to add 101 -p arguments. Is there any way to specify the range in the command line? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Give it as a range

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 8000:8000 -p 5000-5100:5000-5100 container_name
```